# Counting the number of lines in the text file C++

Tags: c++

How to count the number of lines in the text file. 
I've tried with the following code but the output is always 0. 
user will input the .txt file he/she wants to read in, then the program will count the number of lines in the file.

Edit:

```
   ifstream in (infile.c_str(), ios::in);
    if(!in.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error - opening file: " << infile << endl;
        return;
    }

    while(!in.eof())
    {
        in >> type;
        if(in.fail()) break;
        //read corresponding object

        if(type == "Point2D,")
        {
            in >> p2d;
            //add to container
            points2d.push_back(p2d);
        }

        else if(type == "Point3D,")
        {
            in >> p3d;
            //add to container
            points3d.push_back(p3d);
        }

        else if(type == "Line2D,")
        {
            in >> line2d;
            //add to container
            lines2d.push_back(line2d);
        }

        else if(type == "Line3D,")
        {
            in >> line3d;
           //add to container
            lines3D.push_back(line3d);
        }
    }
 in.close();

while (getline(in, line))
    ++noOfRec;
    cout << noOfRec<<" records reading successfully!" << endl;
   //return 0;
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the file is opened successfully?

Comment: yes the file is opened successfully. tried it before i added the count line code

Comment: As @chris suggested, use if(!in.is_open()) to check file opened successfully or not.

Comment: What type, exactly, is noOfRec - if it is not a simple int then this may be the problem, e.g. if it is passed in as a pointer.

Comment: noOfRec is an integer, declared it already

Comment: please see the updated file

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something about the question?  In the example code you close the stream right before the loop that tries to count lines. Not to mention in the big while loop you read from the stream until you can't anymore (so even if you didn't close the stream there wouldn't be any lines left to read).

Answer (score 2):

```
 in.close();
```

You already closed the file.
You should open it again or put back get pointer to beginning of file using seekg()

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() // <-------- HERE
{
   int c=0;
   string s;
   cin >> s; // include extension
   fstream input(s.c_str());
   while (getline(input, s))
     c++;
   cout << c << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: if i add in 'return 0' there will be error.------
` return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: then remove it. my main function return a value. its int main not void main.